# Use an existing instance of IE unless it contains a specified string

Tags: powershell

I am using this code to determine whether to use an existing or new instance of IE:

```
$newInstance = $false
if (Get-Process iexplore -ea silentlycontinue | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}) {
    $ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" } | Select-Object -First 1
    $newInstance = $false
} else {
    $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $newInstance = $true
}

# Elsewhere, I open an array of sites depending on what tabs are already open
foreach ($tab in (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" }) {
    if ($tab.LocationURL.Contains("~"))
    { $search = $true; break }
}
```

If a tab is open that has specified text in its title, how can I ignore that instance of IE, and use a second instance to open an array of sites in? I have tried this:

```
$ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" -and $_.LocationName -like ""}
if ($null -ne $ie) {
    $ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" } | Select-Object -First 1
    $newInstance = $false
} else {
    $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $newInstance = $true
}
```

Comment: Not so clear what you want to do.

Comment: If an instance exists that contains a specified string in its title, then I want to ignore it when determining whether to use an existing or new instance. If the unwanted instance exists, then open a second one, and use that as the existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for?

```
$searchString = "something"
$ie = (New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | where {$_.Name -eq 'Internet Explorer' -and $_.LocationName -like "*$searchString*"}
if ($null -ne $ie) {
    # existing instance found
    $newInstance = $false
}
else {
    # create new instance
    $ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    $newInstance = $true
}
```

Comment: Should I be changing `$instance` to `$ie`, and setting `$newInstance` as above?

Comment: @user2319146 Probably yes, I don't fully understand your desired behavior.

Comment: I want to create an exception for a window with "something" in its title. If "something" and another instance exist, then set `$ie` to use the other instance and `$newInstance = $false`. If only "something" exists, then set `$ie` to use a new instance and `$newInstance = $true`.

Comment: @user2319146 See my edit. But keep in mind that Stackoverflow is for getting help with a specific problem. We do not write all the code for you.

Comment: Thank you; I tried that and other permutations to solve my problem, but I cannot get IE to open at all. The logic seems to be: if a window with "something" in its title does not exist, then there is an existing instance (not necessarily so); else create a new one. I tried adding `$ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" } | Select-Object -First 1` to the first test to tell the script to use any existing window without "something" in its title.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working; improvements appreciated.

```
$newInstance = $false
if (Get-Process iexplore -ea silentlycontinue | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}) {
    if ((New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" -and $_.LocationName -notlike "**" }) {
        $ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" } | Select-Object -First 1
        $newInstance = $false
    } else {
        $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
        $newInstance = $true
    }
} else {
    $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $newInstance = $true
}
```